# How can I host a node js script on vercel

Tags: node.js, heroku, bots, vercel, heroku-cli

I have this node js script/ price checking bot powered by web3.

The job is to check the price of a token eg ETH/USDT on diffrent exchanges to try to spot an arbitrage opportunity.

The code is

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const http = require('http')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')
const moment = require('moment-timezone')
const numeral = require('numeral')
const _ = require('lodash')
const axios = require('axios')

// SERVER CONFIG
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))

// WEB3 CONFIG
const web3 = new Web3(process.env.RPC_URL)

// Uniswap Factory Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xc0a47dfe034b400b47bdad5fecda2621de6c4d95#code
const UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI = [{"name":"NewExchange","inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token","indexed":true},{"type":"address","name":"exchange","indexed":true}],"anonymous":false,"type":"event"},{"name":"initializeFactory","outputs":[],"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"template"}],"constant":false,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":35725},{"name":"createExchange","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"out"}],"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token"}],"constant":false,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":187911},{"name":"getExchange","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"out"}],"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"token"}],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":715},{"name":"getToken","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"out"}],"inputs":[{"type":"address","name":"exchange"}],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":745},{"name":"getTokenWithId","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"out"}],"inputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"token_id"}],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":736},{"name":"exchangeTemplate","outputs":[{"type":"address","name":"out"}],"inputs":[],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":633},{"name":"tokenCount","outputs":[{"type":"uint256","name":"out"}],"inputs":[],"constant":true,"payable":false,"type":"function","gas":663}]
const UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0xc0a47dfe034b400b47bdad5fecda2621de6c4d95'
const uniswapFactoryContract = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI, UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS)

// Uniswap Exchange Template: https://etherscan.io/address/0x09cabec1ead1c0ba254b09efb3ee13841712be14#code
const UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI = [{"name": "TokenPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "EthPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "AddLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "RemoveLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Transfer", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Approval", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "setup", "outputs": [], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 175875}, {"name": "addLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_liquidity"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 82616}, {"name": "removeLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "amount"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 116814}, {"name": "__default__", "outputs": [], "inputs": [], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function"}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12757}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12965}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50463}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50671}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47503}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47712}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50175}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50384}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51007}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51098}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 54928}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 55019}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49342}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49532}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53233}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53423}, {"name": "getEthToTokenInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5542}, {"name": "getEthToTokenOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6872}, {"name": "getTokenToEthInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5637}, {"name": "getTokenToEthOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6897}, {"name": "tokenAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1413}, {"name": "factoryAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1443}, {"name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1645}, {"name": "transfer", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 75034}, {"name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 110907}, {"name": "approve", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 38769}, {"name": "allowance", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1925}, {"name": "name", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1623}, {"name": "symbol", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1653}, {"name": "decimals", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1683}, {"name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1713}]

// Kyber mainnet "Expected Rate": https://etherscan.io/address/0x96b610046d63638d970e6243151311d8827d69a5#readContract
const KYBER_RATE_ABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"alerter","type":"address"}],"name":"removeAlerter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"pendingAdmin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOperators","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sendTo","type":"address"}],"name":"withdrawToken","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newAlerter","type":"address"}],"name":"addAlerter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"transferAdmin","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newFactor","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setQuantityFactor","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"claimAdmin","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"transferAdminQuickly","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getAlerters","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address[]"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOperator","type":"address"}],"name":"addOperator","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"worstCaseRateFactorInBps","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"quantityFactor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"removeOperator","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"kyberNetwork","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"sendTo","type":"address"}],"name":"withdrawEther","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dest","type":"address"},{"name":"srcQty","type":"uint256"},{"name":"usePermissionless","type":"bool"}],"name":"getExpectedRate","outputs":[{"name":"expectedRate","type":"uint256"},{"name":"slippageRate","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getBalance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"bps","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setWorstCaseRateFactor","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"admin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_kyberNetwork","type":"address"},{"name":"_admin","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newFactor","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"oldFactor","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sender","type":"address"}],"name":"QuantityFactorSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newMin","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"oldMin","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sender","type":"address"}],"name":"MinSlippageFactorSet","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sendTo","type":"address"}],"name":"TokenWithdraw","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"sendTo","type":"address"}],"name":"EtherWithdraw","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"pendingAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"TransferAdminPending","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newAdmin","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"previousAdmin","type":"address"}],"name":"AdminClaimed","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newAlerter","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"isAdd","type":"bool"}],"name":"AlerterAdded","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newOperator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"isAdd","type":"bool"}],"name":"OperatorAdded","type":"event"}]
const KYBER_RATE_ADDRESS = '0x96b610046d63638d970e6243151311d8827d69a5'
const kyberRateContract = new web3.eth.Contract(KYBER_RATE_ABI, KYBER_RATE_ADDRESS)

async function checkPair(args) {
  const { inputTokenSymbol, inputTokenAddress, outputTokenSymbol, outputTokenAddress, inputAmount } = args

  const exchangeAddress = await uniswapFactoryContract.methods.getExchange(outputTokenAddress).call()
  const exchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI, exchangeAddress)

  const uniswapResult = await exchangeContract.methods.getEthToTokenInputPrice(inputAmount).call()
  let kyberResult = await kyberRateContract.methods.getExpectedRate(inputTokenAddress, outputTokenAddress, inputAmount, true).call()

  console.table([{
    'Input Token': inputTokenSymbol,
    'Output Token': outputTokenSymbol,
    'Input Amount': web3.utils.fromWei(inputAmount, 'Ether'),
    'Uniswap Return': web3.utils.fromWei(uniswapResult, 'Ether'),
    'Kyber Expected Rate': web3.utils.fromWei(kyberResult.expectedRate, 'Ether'),
    'Kyber Min Return': web3.utils.fromWei(kyberResult.slippageRate, 'Ether'),
    'Timestamp': moment().tz('America/Chicago').format(),
  }])
}

let priceMonitor
let monitoringPrice = false

async function monitorPrice() {
  if(monitoringPrice) {
    return
  }

  console.log("Checking prices...")
  monitoringPrice = true

  try {

    // ADD YOUR CUSTOM TOKEN PAIRS HERE!!!

    await checkPair({
      inputTokenSymbol: 'ETH',
      inputTokenAddress: '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      outputTokenSymbol: 'MKR',
      outputTokenAddress: '0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2',
      inputAmount: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ETHER')
    })

    await checkPair({
      inputTokenSymbol: 'ETH',
      inputTokenAddress: '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      outputTokenSymbol: 'DAI',
      outputTokenAddress: '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f',
      inputAmount: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ETHER')
    })

    await checkPair({
      inputTokenSymbol: 'ETH',
      inputTokenAddress: '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      outputTokenSymbol: 'KNC',
      outputTokenAddress: '0xdd974d5c2e2928dea5f71b9825b8b646686bd200',
      inputAmount: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ETHER')
    })

    await checkPair({
      inputTokenSymbol: 'ETH',
      inputTokenAddress: '0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',
      outputTokenSymbol: 'LINK',
      outputTokenAddress: '0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca',
      inputAmount: web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ETHER')
    })

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    monitoringPrice = false
    clearInterval(priceMonitor)
    return
  }

  monitoringPrice = false
}

// Check markets every n seconds
const POLLING_INTERVAL = process.env.POLLING_INTERVAL || 3000 // 3 Seconds
priceMonitor = setInterval(async () => { await monitorPrice() }, POLLING_INTERVAL)
```

To run the script from my laptop I use the command:
`$ node index.js`

The script is working the way I expect it to. But the issue is that my pc has to be constantly online for the script to keep running.

But how can I put this script on a server so that I can be running 24hrs/365days

Can I put the script on vercel?? If no what other hosting platforms do you recommend and also steps to deploy to those platforms. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't host a nodejs script to vercel.

But You may use **Heroku** free tier but it's limited.

**Deploy in Heroku**

1. Push the code to GitHub
2. Attach GitHub repo to Heroku
3. Commit code and it'll auto-deploy your app

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try heroku

Comment: yes u can host node js on vercel

Answer (score 0):

You can host any Node.js script on Vercel - it's called serverless functions:

1. Create an [API route](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) that calls your script
2. Create a [CRON](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/solutions/cron-jobs) (with Github Actions or any CRON service) to call the API route on your defined interval
3. Check the free limits of the serverless functions on [this page](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview) and the limits of the CRON service you've chosen

Answer (score 0):

Firstly all the work is done by the vercel itself all u have to do is added a vercel.json file in directory [image: like this]
and in the vercel.json file u have to add the below code

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds":[
    {
        "src":"./index.js",
        "use":"@vercel/node"
    }
],

"routes":[
    {
        "src":"/(.*)",
        "dest":"/"
    }
   ] 
   }
```

and make sure u add the correct path to index.js